# preserving backslash-newlines in heredocs run in a subshell

Tags: bash, here-document

So long as terminal backslashes are not present, the newlines of a heredoc are preserved after capturing the output of a heredoc in a variable:

```
var=$(cat <<-EOF
a
b
c
EOF
)
echo "$var"

a
b
c
```

Newlines are lost, however, when trying to store backslash-newlines:

```
var=$(cat <<-EOF
a \\
b \\
c
EOF
)

echo "$var"
a \b \c
```

Adding additional backslashes for further escaping does not help.

Of course, when not run in a subshell, a heredoc can be used to generate lines that end in backslash-newline:

```
$ cat <<-EOF
a \\
b \\
c
EOF
a \
b \
c
```

To circumvent this problem, one can add a newline delimiter to generate the desired output by a transformation of the variable:

```
var=$(cat <<-EOF
a \\@
b \\@
c
EOF
)

tr -d '@' <<<"$var"

a \
b \
c
```

Is there a more straightforward way to preserve backslash-newlines from heredocs run in subshells?

Comment: Perhaps you could consider avoiding the command substitution altogether - for example using `read` to assign the here-doc's stdout to a variable directly, and explicitly turning off interpretation of backslash escapes with `-r`: `read -r -d '' var << EOF ... `

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks, that's a good idea. I hadn't thought of using `-d ''` to allow multi-line inputs to be read into a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if that's a bug in Bash (or if the behaviour of backslash-newlines is just undefined). All other shells I tried show different behaviour from Bash:

```
$ cat nl.sh

echo "1:"
cat <<EOF
a \\
b \\
c
EOF

echo "2:"
var=$(cat <<-EOF
a \\
b \\
c
EOF
)
echo "$var"
```

output:

```
$ bash nl.sh
1:
a \
b \
c
2:
a \b \c
```

vs.

```
$ dash nl.sh
1:
a \
b \
c
2:
a \
b \
c
```

You could put the code inside the command substitution in a function, that might help in working around any issues with the parser, e.g.:

```
f() {
cat <<EOF
a \\
b
EOF
}
var=$(f)
echo "$var"
```

Comment: Yes, there have been fixes recently in `bash` about that. `cat << 'EOF'` now works as expected, but there are still bugs with `cat << EOF`

Comment: With bash 4.4.20, `cat << 'EOF'` appears to give the desired behaviour when using the "old-style  backquote form" of command substitution - but not when using the `$(...)` form. The man page alludes to differences between the two forms, but I'm unable to determine from that whether the behaviour is by design or considered a bug.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, hmm, ok. I don't remember seeing that on bug-bash, but I admit I didn't look too closely

Comment: See parse.y
        - parse_comsub: if we are parsing a here document with a quoted
          delimiter (LEX_QUOTEDDOC), we should not remove <backslash><newline>
          pairs from the body of the here document.  Need to add LEX_QUOTEDDOC
          to the values in tflags when calling shell_getc.  Fixes bug reported
          by Michael Homer <michael.homer@ecs.vuw.ac.nz>, patch was originally
          contributed by Geir Hauge <geir.hauge@gmail.com> in the changelog

Comment: @steeldriver, the latest version of bash is 5.0.7.

Comment: Well, it's good that other shells behave according to naive expectations.  Protecting inside a function is a useful workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to cause the new-line character to be force expanded inside a here-doc. But you can use a variable that contains an encoded newline character using ANSI escape sequence (`$'\n'`) and make the variable expansion happen inside the heredoc.

Note that this form of hereodoc expansion would need your de-limiter `'EOF'` to be unquoted i.e. something as below,

```
nl=$'\n'
```

and use the `$nl` variable as a placeholder for the newline character

```
var=$(cat <<-EOF
a $nl
b $nl
c
EOF
)
```

which now properly emits

```
echo "$var"
a 

b 

c
```

Comment: Thanks, using `$'\n'` in a variable works; I implemented as follows: `var=$(cat <<EOF[\n]a \\${nl}b \\${nl}c[\n]EOF[\n])` where `[\n]` denotes an actual newline (input by pressing Return on the keyboard), which was necessary here since stackexchange comments are obligatorily single-line.